# Spring AMQP recoverer not working with SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to implement the recovery in spring amqp. I have used below code to implement the same

```
RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptorBuilder =RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .recoverer(new CustomRejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .build();

container.setAdviceChain(new RetryOperationsInterceptor[]{retryInterceptorBuilder});
```

The above container is the instance of `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. Now in one of my receivers I am throwing `ClassCastException`.

```
public class CustomRejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer implements MessageRecoverer {


    private static Logger logger = //created some logger instance.

    //Overriding the method to do custom task when the retries are exhausted, like insert in database.
    @Override
    public void recover(Message message, Throwable cause) {
        logger.error("The recovery method is called","","");
        throw new RuntimeException(cause);
    }

}
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Update :

Some exception is thrown in my CustomMessagingPostProcessor. My RetryOperationsInterceptor  only retries the messages if the exception is thrown in onMessage() method. Adding definition of CustomMessagingPostProcessor:-

```java
public class MTMessagingPostProcessor implements MessagePostProcessor{



    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) {
        logger.xdebug("Inside MTMessagingPostProcessor", 

          //Throwing exception to show that some exception can be thrown in original code and I want to requeue messages to come here for n number of times.
            throw new RuntimeException("TEST");
        //return message;
    }


    public void setTenantProvider(TenantProvider tenantProvider) {
        this.tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }


}
```

I want to requeue messages n number of times if exception is thrown in MTMessagingPostProcessor, this is not achieved by interceptor as it retries messages in onMessage() method of the listener.

Comment: Can you add the full exception stack trace ?

Comment: Why are you throwing a `RuntimeException` in your recoverer? The whole point is to "recover" the situation and handle the exception. Of course, that doesn't help with your question as to why the recoverer is not being called; please add the complete configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell.. Thanks for quick reply, I have added more code and updated the question a bit. Please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you are providing a `MessagePostProcessor` in the `afterReceiveMessagePostProcessors` container property, those post processors are called outside the scope of the advice chain (retry interceptors).

You can't "retry" exceptions thrown by such post processors.

The retry interceptor applies only to the listener itself.

Comment: Gary Russell -- What is your recommendation in those cases, because we are facing such issue in our production environment?

Comment: Such errors should be considered fatal and you should either handle them in the post processor directly, or handle them in a custom error handler in the container. The default error handler is a `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler`.

Comment: Gary Russell --- Is there any way in Spring AMQP to achieve few times retries in case of Exception is thrown from MessagePostProcessor?

Comment: No; message post processors must not throw an exception; if you want to discard a message because it is bad, simply return `null` from the MPP. If you want to retry you would have to implement it in your MPP.